# Nginx Access denied in windows 10

Tags: php, windows, nginx, wamp

i have installed google drive desktop app and wamp.net in my windows 10 system. i am try on local environment using nginx+php but, when try to access site from my google drive path (D:\My Drive\example.com) then get access denied error, if try from another local disk (C:\www\example.com) like "C" or other then work fine and if i try using apache+php from google drive disk (D:\My Drive\example.com) then work fine. only problem with nginx and from google drive disk only not other local disk.

here is my nginx log:

```
[crit] 12672#7524: *1 GetFileAttributesEx() "D:/My Drive/localhost/" failed (5: Access is denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

please help me to fix.. thank you

Comment: No idea how *Google Drive Desktop* works but what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: i try to use wamp.net (php environment) in windows for php project

Comment: Then use your `C:` disk ? What are you trying to accomplish with the *Google Drive* disk ?

Comment: because automatic sync files on google drive after update any files or folder.

Comment: I think I get it, you're trying to save your work in Google Drive ? Have you ever heard of **Git** ?

Comment: heard but not know what is use of git..

Comment: Well, using Google Drive as a storage for your code is only seen in [memes](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8jtxrn/the_best_way_of_saving_your_code/), you shouldn't do that. You can learn **Git** from the [official website](https://git-scm.com/) and there's also good [guides provided by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git). It worths the time invested.